# Is the inverse of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix also a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

If we let $$S_{++}^n(\mathbb{R})$$

denote the set of all  **square** symmetric positive definite matrix over the real numbers, then is it true if $A\in S_{++}(\mathbb{R}) \implies A^{-1} \in S_{++}(\mathbb{R})$?

**EDIT** Never mind, if the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are the inverse of $A$ So $A \in S_{++}  \iff A ^{-1} \in S_{++}$. This answers my own question.

Comment: Sorry a typo. I fixed and answered my own question

Comment: What typo? Everyone can see the edit history and you changed almost half the question. What "answered my own question"? the edit was done after the question had already been answered and you never even bothered to mark it as accepted. In the time you took to "answer your own question" @JPi could've answered it 3 times over and still have time to spare.

Answer (score 19):

First, if a matrix is positive semidefinite then it can have eigenvalues equal to zero, in which case it is singular.

If it is positive definite (using the most common definition, i.e. symmetric and with positive eigenvalues) then the answer is yes since the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: If any positive semidefinite matrix is non-singular, then it is also positive definite right?

Comment: The Laplacian matrix is a good example of a positive semi-definite matrix that is singular (by design).

Comment: @Canine360 yes.